# Spring boot using Postman when making a POST with foreign key is returning null

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post, request, postman

I am trying to make a post request using POSTMAN with Spring Boot

The relation between User and Role is (ManyToOne).

Why does role returns this:  ("role":null)

POSTMAN VIEW:
 {

```
    "name": "usertest",
    "lastname": "usertest",
    "email": "usertest@gmail.com",
    "role": {
        "id": 1


    }
}
```

POSTMAN OUTPUT:

```
{
    "id": 29,
    "name": "usertest",
    "lastname": "usertest",
    "email": "usertest@gmail.com",
    "role": {
        "id": 1,
        "role": null
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
@PostMapping("user")
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        try {
            userService.save(user);
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                    .headers(httpHeaders)
                    .body(user);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

ENTITY USER:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Role role;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mapping the input request body to a **User** object and persisting it into DB by calling `userService.save(user)` and you are NOT re-initializing `user` property with the persisted entity reference. So, it is a plain POJO, not a JPA managed entity. That's why the "role" property is still null.

You could return the persistent user from `userService.save(user)` method and return that from the Controller method. Also. you need to take care of loading Role inside User as it is a LAZY property.